# PHP: Comment reply system with quotes. How can I display the parent (quoted) message to the child (reply) message

Tags: php, mysql, comments

### How can I display the parent (quoted) message to the child (reply) message

```
Database structure:
post_id
comment_id
message
parent_id


SQL data:
post_id: 1
comment_id: 10
message: boohooo
parent_id: 0
------------------
post_id: 1
comment_id: 20
message: another reply
parent_id: 0
------------------
post_id: 1
comment_id: 30
messsage: you are scary
parent_id: 10
```

Here is a code below (translated from mysql results to php) whit what i have so far

```
<?php 
$first_comment = new stdClass;
$first_comment->cid = '1';
$first_comment->message = 'this is the first message';
$first_comment->parent = '0';

$second_comment = new stdClass;
$second_comment->cid = '20';
$second_comment->message = 'this is the second message';
$second_comment->parent = '0';

$third_comment = new stdClass;
$third_comment->cid = '30';
$third_comment->message = 'this is a reply to the first message';
$third_comment->parent = '10';

$comments = array ($first_comment, $second_comment, $third_comment);

//print_r($comments);

foreach ( $comments as $c ) {
echo "#". $c->cid . "  ". $c->message . "\n\n";
}
?>
```

*The same code can be fiddle with on this php sandbox site:  http://ideone.com/fwHUwv*

I want it to be outputted like this:

#### Comments:

#10. **boohooo**

  #20. **another reply**

  #30. *boohooo*

  **you are scary**

Comment: Can't you paste those 23 lines of code here?? But, more important, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$first_comment = new stdClass;
$first_comment->cid = '1';
$first_comment->message = 'this is the first message';
$first_comment->parent = '0';

$second_comment = new stdClass;
$second_comment->cid = '2';
$second_comment->message = 'this is the second message';
$second_comment->parent = '0';

$third_comment = new stdClass;
$third_comment->cid = '3';
$third_comment->message = 'this is a reply to the first message';
$third_comment->parent = '1';

$comments = array ($first_comment, $second_comment, $third_comment);

//print_r($comments);

foreach ( $comments as $c ) {
    if($c->parent != 0) { echo "#". $c->cid . "  ". $comments[$c->parent-1]->message . "\n"; echo $c->message; } 
    else {
        echo "#". $c->cid . "  ". $c->message . "\n\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
#1  this is the first message

#2  this is the second message

#3  this is the first message
this is a reply to the first message
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the comment ids (cid) are not consecutive. I'm getting a _PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9 in ...._

see:
http://ideone.com/4l85ra